# GitHub webhook-action after push/pull-request

Tags: git, github-actions, webhooks

I work on some project, which is already runs on ubuntu server. I have a task to implement CI/CD in this project: when i push or pull-request in GiHub development branch, project should pull all changes and rerun on server. I need to do this only with ubuntu tools and GitHub (actions). Thinking about the problem, I came to the conclusion that it possible to do with webhook on server and webhook-action. My question is **"How should I run my custom webhook AFTER successful push or pull-request merge?"**. In my mind, in workflow if i trigger push or pull-request, actions run after event trigger and before immediate push/pull-request (Or i'm wrong?). Maybe, there is something else, which I can do to imlement CI/CD?

Project works in docker compose with Django, gunicorn, postgresql and traefik. I have to not use DockerHub and actions for build and push image in it, and then pull it on server side. It would be too easy.

Comment: Probably, The solution is building my images in some action and then deploy them on my server with scp command or something else?

Comment: What do you mean with "it would be too easy"? Is this homework?

Comment: @rethab yes, it is.

Comment: Okay. So I'm not willing to do the homework for you. If you have a specific question or problem, I'm happy to give you some hints though.

Comment: No problem. The main question was this: "How should I run my custom webhook AFTER successful push or pull-request merge?", but I've understood, that all actions exec after events like push or pull-request. So, now my question is "Am I thinking in the right direction: to implement ci/cd i need to build images in workflow job, then deploy them on server using ssh tools like scp and then up all deployed images?". If the answer is "No", put me on the right track.

Comment: I'd say typically an image is pushed to a registry and then it is pulled on the server (e.g. kubernetes would pull the image). However, you can also use SCP or something to push it there.